# sql like command combines words

Tags: sql, compare

I have this sql command: `select name from criminals where name || surname like '%SH%' order by id;`

The problem is that my results show also the name "LambroS" "Hitiris" just because the last name letter and the first surname letter form "SH". How can I fix that? I want to show results if either one of them CONTAINS these letters.

Comment: Have you tried adding a space between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   CRIMINALS 
WHERE  NAME 
       || ' ' 
       || SURNAME LIKE '%SH%' 
ORDER  BY ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use OR:

```
select name from criminals where name like '%SH%' OR surname like '%SH%'
```